# Zip files in a folder and give the archive folder's name

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I'm very new to php and I just made my first script, which is working fine, but is missing a final touch.
The script zips all files in the folder containing the php and creates a downloadable archive.
Here's the code

```
<?php

$zipname =  'test.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open('D://mypath//zip//$zipname', ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($dir_handle = opendir('./')) {
  while (false !== ($entry = readdir($dir_handle))) {
    if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && !strstr($entry,'.php') && !strstr($entry,'.zip')) {
      $zip->addFile($entry);
    }
  }
  closedir($dir_handle);
}
else {
  die('file not found');
}

$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$zipname");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
header("Location: $zipname");

?>
```

What I'd like to achieve is having $zipname = "the name of the folder.zip" 
So, if the php is inside "/mypath/blablabla/" i want my zip $zipname to be "blablabla.zip"

Any help will be appreciated!

EDIT: 
here's the working code:

```
<?php
$zipname = getcwd();
$zipname = substr($zipname,strrpos($zipname,'\\')+1);
$zipname = $zipname.'.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open('D:/inetpub/webs/mydomaincom/zip/'.basename($zipname).'', ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($dir_handle = opendir('./')) {
  while (false !== ($entry = readdir($dir_handle))) {
if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && !strstr($entry,'.php')) {
    $zip->addFile($entry);
}
}
closedir($dir_handle);
}
else {
die('file not found');
}

$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($zipname).'"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
header('Location: /zip/'.$zipname);
?>
```

Comment: And you can't find a function to get path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use getcwd() :

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.getcwd.php

```
$zipname = getcwd();
```

It'll return the path of the current folder, then you could just hash the result to get only the name of the folder :

```
// We remove all the uneeded part of the path
$zipname = substr($zipname,strrpos($zipname,'\\')+1);

//Then we add .zip to the result :
$zipname = $zipname.'.zip';
```

This should do the trick.

And if you want to also use the name of the parent folder :

```
$zipname = getcwd();

// We remove the uneeded part of the path
$parentFolderPath = substr($zipname, 0,strrpos($zipname,'\\'));
$parentFolder = substr($parentFolderPath, strrpos($parentFolderPath,'\\')+1);

//Keep current folder name
$currentFolder = substr($zipname,strrpos($zipname,'\\')+1);

//Join both
$zipname = $parentFolder.'_'.$currentFolder;

//Then we add .zip to the result :
$zipname = $zipname.'.zip';
```

Comment: No prob, don't forget to put your question as resolved :)

Comment: Actually it's not resolved yet. I can't get the file to download properly (downloaded archive is empty, but i can see that the archive is being created properly on the server). I think it's because the archive is saved to a different directory and i'm not that good with headers...

Comment: Well your question was about naming your zip file with the name of your folder, which is what is doing the code that I gave you ^^'

You can still open another question with your updated code to see why your file isn't downloading properly.

Comment: And what if I wanted to include also the name of the parent folder?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redirecting with `header()`, you could use `readfile()`:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($zipname).'"');
readfile($zipname);
```

With `basename()` only the last part is shown to the user and with `readfile()` you are giving out the actual file, no matter where it is.

Comment: readfile($zipname) points me to download an empty archive with the correct name.  note that the zip archive is not created in the same folder i'm zipping, it actually resides in a /zip/ folder. how do i point to that?